# tailgateui page doesnt look like as in their website

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to test tailwindui using their free examples.
For example I copy paste the HTML for the page section exampe to a file and open with my chrome
https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes

It looks completely messed up/massive lines scaled up, pieced are all over, definitely doesn't look like in the web page. What am I missing?

Your Company
                    
                  
                  
                    
                      Open main menu
                      
                      
                        
                      
                    
                  
                
              
              
                Product
  
                Features
  
                Marketplace
  
                Company
  
                Log in
              
            
          
  
          
          
            
              
                
                  
                
                
                  
                    Close main menu
                    
                    
                      
                    
                  
                
              
              
                Product
  
                Features
  
                Marketplace
  
                Company
              
              Log in
            
          
        
  
        
          
            
              Data to enrich your
              online business
            
            Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat fugiat aliqua.
            
              
                Get started
              
              
                Live demo